# R scripts completely blank (I have a backup) - how to fix?

Tags: r, windows

I have a number of R scripts saved on my work laptop. I updated the R version from 4.1.1 to 4.2.1 (most recent version) on this laptop.

When I tried to open the scripts on my work laptop after the update, they were ALL completely blank - even the ones I was not working on, nor even had open, at the time of the update. The script files themselves still exist and are said to contain data according to file properties (i.e: they aren't said to be 0kb), but when opened, there is nothing in them - no code, comments, etc.

I can see all the code again by opening the "blank" file, selecting 'reopen with encoding', and selecting 'UTF-8'. However, I have to do this every time I open the file, and it doesn't feel that 'secure'.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What are you using to open them? Did you try just a plain text editor? E.g. NotePad or TextEdit

Comment: Dan Adams - I just use RStudio. They show up fine after setting the default encoding option to UTF-8. Do you know if this would be a long-term solution? I'm afraid I have no idea what encoding even is.

Comment: Isaac, as Dan has suggested, I'd try opening one of the blank R scripts in a text editor. I'd also try opening with Rgui.exe. What is your operating system?

Comment: Also, what RStudio version are you using?

Comment: [Source pane displays non-empty R script as empty #1623](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1623)

Comment: [Blank Source window when opening R script](https://community.rstudio.com/t/blank-source-window-when-opening-r-script/115372)

Comment: Install the latest "daily", i.e. development version https://dailies.rstudio.com/.